# Wordpress filter to handle custom action button on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress

I have created custom post type called `campaign`, then I have create custom action button using `post_row_actions` filter like this.

```
function hipwee_add_action_button($actions, $post){

    if(get_post_type() === 'campaign'){
        $actions['export'] = '<a href="#">Export Result</a>';
    }
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'hipwee_add_action_button', 10, 2 );
```

as you can see above, I added new action button called "Export Result",
but now, how to add a function to handle the export, is there available wordpress filter to put my custom action handler?

[image: custom-button-action]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function hipwee_add_action_button($actions, $post){

    if(get_post_type() === 'campaign'){
        $url = add_query_arg(
            array(
              'post_id' => $post->ID,
              'my_action' => 'custom_export_post',
            )
          );
    $actions['export'] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '" target="_blank"    >Export Result</a>';
    }
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'hipwee_add_action_button', 10, 2 );

add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_export_function' );

function custom_export_function(){
  if ( isset( $_REQUEST['my_action'] ) && 
   'custom_export_post' == $_REQUEST['my_action']  ) {
    $data = array(
      'hello' => 'world'
      );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.json"');
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
  }
}
```

**What it does:**

When `Export Result` button is clicked, it opens new window with parameter `my_action` with value `custom_export_post`. Now another function `custom_export_function` is hooked to `admin_init`. This function acts as the main exporter. In the example a sample array is exported to JSON file. You can now customize function as you require.

Comment: great, i have tried and seems worked.
thanks for your time, so the best hook i can use is `admin_init`?